# How to specify gRPC server address target on client side when the service is on format <my-service:port>

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc

We are using grpc spring boot starter on our Java application service in order to establish a connection to another 'server' service, so I define in the `application.properties` the following address:

```
grpc.client.name.address=static://service-name:port
```

When tried to connect it I got the following error message:

```
StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

So I know for sure I have a connectivity issue. On the [documentation](https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/client/configuration.html) it says regarding the static scheme:

> A simple static list of IPs (both v4 and v6), that can be use connect to the server

So I guess this is not what I need to use. It seems the best option in my case is using the `discovery` scheme, but it doesn't contains any port...

What is the right scheme configuration I need to use to set the server address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanted to share the resolution for this very annoying issue for those who will encounter the same problem in the future like I did.

So first, the scheme needs to be set indeed of `dns` type, like the following: `grpc.client._name_.address=dns:///<service-name>:26502`
but this alone is not enough. (at least in my case) The server was configured to run in `PLAINTEXT`, while my client, by default, was configured to run with `TLS` mode, so it must be set with `grpc.client.__name__.negotiationType=PLAINTEXT` property.

See the following [documentation](https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/trouble-shooting.html) for further information

Answer (score 1):

It caused by gRPC can't resolve addresss `service-name:port`;

If you use `static`, the value must be `ip:port`; The `service-name` need to be resolved as ip address;

If you are using register center like consul or eureka etc., you should use `discovery:///service-name` without specify port.

If you didn't use register center, only end to end with server, replace `service-name` as a ip like `127.0.0.1` which belong to server;

Or modify host config for parse `service-name` like below, the file on Linux is `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 service-name
```

Comment: What about the 'dns' option? will in work with dns:port?

Comment: @Nimrod Does you `service-name` is a dns  can be parsed as address correctly? And dns doesn't need port.

Comment: The service name dns can be parsed into an address. I tried using 'dns:///my-grpc-server-app:1234' as a configuration, but I still getting UNAVAILABLE: io exception

Comment: How do you make suere it can parse correctly,  try use `dig my-grpc-server-app` and does it has address?  UNAVAILABLE is caused by can't connect. And try to set log level to debug to find more message.